# Newly submitted Podfile won't install with pod install but instead installs with pod install --repo-update

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

I have created a new iOS framework in which I listed external cocoapods as dependancies in my podspec file.

I successfully ran podspec lint without warnings/errors and then pushed the trunk which was also successful.

I read in several places that it usually takes up to an hour to show up so after 2 hours I tried to integrate the pod into a demo project using `pod install`, it gave me some errors like:

- This pod might no longer be available
- There could be an issue with the repository link
- The name of the pod might be invalid

All of which I disagree to. So upon further research, I saw some people even had to wait for 7 hours as they had quite a heavy project, however, my library is not too heavy and it's dependancies are quite heavy but since they are not included in the project itself, I was wondering why it took so long.

Then I came across another pod install command `pod install --repo-update` which I ran seconds after `pod install` failed and it installed my pod and all of it's dependancies.

So I am curious to know what is the difference between these commands and how come one worked and the other did not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pod install --repo-update` and `pod update` update your local copy of the centralized CocoaPods Specs repository with the latest version.

`pod install` will use the previous local copy on your machine.

If a pod publisher published a new version after the last time you updated your local copy, `pod install` won't have access it to it. That's why you need to specify `--repo-update`.

Comment: Thanks for this and while it improves my understanding of the commands, I'm not sure if I get the reasoning. I published a pod to test (1 and only version). After 5 hours, I created a new single view application in an isolated directory to test my pod. I did a ```pod init``` and mentioned the pod in my podfile. I ran ```pod install```, failed. Seconds after failure, I ran ```pod install --repo-update``` as cocoapods itself suggested and now everything installed. I had no pods in the directory prior to running these commands.

Comment: The Pods repo copy is stored at `~/.cocoapods` not in the app's directory

Comment: Agreed, but I never installed any pods to begin with so there is no pods directory or xcworkspace generated for that matter. Maybe I am phrasing something incorrectly that gave you this notion. It's a fresh project XCode Project, never having installed pods previously. However, It seems to be a time issue because today, approx 24 hours later, pod install works on my pod for a fresh project. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: Understood. There is only one `cocoapods` directory in the home directory - not the app/project directory. It's a centralized mirror of the CocoaPods Spec repo for your machine shared by any project, new or old, on your machine.

Comment: Thank you Paul ... now that is something I did not know and makes sense to me now. Thank you for your patience and helping me learn something new .. much appreciated.